# Alter row based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to alter the rows with the following conditions in SQL Server.

1. Merge all rows with similar `code` taking first date from the 1st row and last date from the last row.
2. Un-similar rows will remain as it is.

```
CREATE TABLE ABCD(
    id int,
    FirstDate date,
    LastDate date,
    code varchar(23)
);

Insert into ABCD VALUES
(1, '2022-12-12','2022-12-12', 'A'),
(2, '2022-12-13','2022-12-13', 'A'),
(3, '2022-12-15','2022-12-15', 'A'),
(4, '2022-12-16','2022-2-16', 'B'),
(5, '2022-12-18','2022-12-18', 'A'),
(5, '2022-12-19','2022-12-19', 'A'),
(6, '2022-12-20','2022-12-20', 'C')

SELECT * from ABCD
```

Expected result is

```
(1, '2022-12-12','2022-12-15', 'A'),
(2, '2022-12-16','2022-2-16', 'B'),
(3, '2022-12-18','2022-12-19', 'A'),
(4, '2022-12-20','2022-12-20', 'C')
```

Tried

```
SELECT *
FROM ABCD #A
INNER JOIN ABCD #B on #A.code != #B.code AND #A.id = #B.id
```

I'm unable to think of any logic to get this working. Suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with logic that has a few steps

- First, 'group' the rows together based on whether they're sequential (e.g., the first three A rows, then the B row, etc)

  - To do this, the answer below uses 2 steps: first, find each row that is a 'new' group, and assign those rows a 1. Then do a running total on those - which becomes the grouping value.
- Then, group by that grouping value - and get the minimum and maximum dates.

```
WITH ABCD_with_newvals AS
  (SELECT *, 
         CASE WHEN LAG(code, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) = [code] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NewVal
  FROM ABCD
  ),
  ABCD_grouped AS
  (SELECT *,
         SUM(NewVal) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS GroupNum
  FROM ABCD_with_newvals
  )
SELECT GroupNum, Code, MIN(FirstDate) AS FirstDate, MAX(LastDate) AS LastDate
  FROM ABCD_grouped
  GROUP BY GroupNum, Code
  ORDER BY GroupNum;
```

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hW9xXzz9) with the answer, as well as breaking the steps up so you can see what the data is at each point in the process.

Oh - here are the results

```
GroupNum   Code   FirstDate    LastDate
1          A      2022-12-12   2022-12-15
2          B      2022-12-16   2022-02-16
3          A      2022-12-18   2022-12-19
4          C      2022-12-20   2022-12-20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the following result using the first and last value functions.

```
SELECT distinct
Code,FIRST_VALUE(FirstDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY FirstDate) AS FirstDate    ,
LAST_VALUE(LastDate) OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY LastDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LastDate FROM ABCD
```

[image]